# Testing Spring controller service without ApplicationContext file

Tags: java, spring, servlets, mocking

I've inherited a legacy app which does not contain an ApplicationContext xml file and does not appear to be using ApplicationContext within the application. Below exception is thrown when I attempt to test :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at
```

The application is a Spring app and does contain a controller :

```
@Controller
public class DataController {
```

But I' unsure how to test the controller services without an applicationContext file.

Here is my test class which throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException` :

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.ModelAndViewAssert;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.inject.Inject;

//@ContextConfiguration({/* include live config here
//    e.g. "file:web/WEB-INF/application-context.xml",
//    "file:web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" */})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CustomTest {

        @Inject
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        private MockHttpServletRequest request;
        private MockHttpServletResponse response;
        private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;
        private ReviewController controller;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
            response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
            handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class);
            // I could get the controller from the context here
            controller = new DataController();
        }

        @Test
        public void testFoo() throws Exception {
            request.setRequestURI("/data/get");
            final ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response,
                    controller);
        }
    }
```

How to test `DataController.getData` method with signature  :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/data/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void getData(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("dataId") long id) {
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

And use Mockito for dependencies in DataController.java 
Mock the dependencies and use setter to populate.

Answer (score 0):

Doing integration testing is spring depends on the version of the project and what spring boot version you are using. There is a good article that explains that here (a bit old):

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

That should point you in the right direction.

In my experience in newer apps the spring context is loaded from Java code in the main method of the application. This looks like it might be one of those. In that case you have to have a few things for your integration tests to work:

1. `application.properties` file in your test resources that sets the configuration for testing
2. a test class annotated with `@SpringBootTest`
3. an int property annotated with `@LocalServerPort`

   ```
   @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
   public YourTestClass {

       @LocalServerPort
       private int port

       //your tests here

   }
   ```

Then you can set up tests and call the tests application on the local server port with whatever http client you want (RestTemplate, HttpClient, etc). That seems a bit outside the question to explain though so I will leave that here.